# How to save User-Input Form, To be able to open & edit it later? C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, forms, save

I'm currently busy with a user interface application and I really need some help.

[image: Main Window of my application]

Once 'new order' is clicked, a user **INPUT** window appears, allowing the user to type in the customer's details and select the products the customer wishes to order

[image: User Input Form]

Selecting certain products makes grids appear, allowing the user to specify the measurements of each panel, gate or post according to the customers needs.

[image: Completed Input Form]

Finally once the User clicked 'Save' Two **OUTPUT** forms appear. One for palisade manufacturing, the other for the steel workshop. The output forms contains the exact machine manufacturing specifications to produce the panels etc according to the customers specifications.  (This will later be integrated with the actual machine)

[image]

NOW... I would really like to be able to save the **INPUT** form, so that the user can later reopen the order and make changes or add products to the existing order.

It would be ideal to have an option in the Main Window to open a Form that displays all the orders saved under the customer code, and job number and perhaps the dateStamp. Once the user selects any one of the orders, The **INPUT** window should open with that specific order's input, allowing the user to add products and save under a new date stamp.

The **OUTPUT** Forms are saved as a PDF with the use of iTextSharp, And also printed. Those files however stay unaltered.

Each one of the Datagrids are temporarily bound with DataTables, The Customer details however are just textboxes stored in variables. ((The input Values undergo a series of calculations and are used to preform LOOKUP's in excel sheets to return information needed for manufacturing, and parts indexes)))

I also tried creating a dataBase, but I couldnt get that to work. Most Customer & Order Databases rely on the relating columns, such as product codes, customer codes, etc. However, I basically only have information sheets. Its hard enough to bind multiple datagrids to a specific customer. Its even harder when all the data grids pretty much have the same columns. Height, Width, Qty, etc...

If any one has any advice or raging responses 'cause of my stupidity.. I would REALLY appreciate it. This is my very first C# application... My first actual user application to be honest. I need to get started with the VHDL

Thanks in advance

Herman Vercuiel

Comment: Let me know if this is silly... I guess what I can do, is export the dataTables to a CSV file. saving that file under the customer code etc. And then create a Form with a table displaying all the orders... Although, I don't think you can have a different 'event' for clicking on each row. And also, my application has instantaneous response. I'd hate for that to change now...

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back from the application itself and consider what the actual objects you're creating are. It seems like you'll get alot of benefit from creating classes such as Customer, Order, etc... You don't necessarily need a database, a text file could work fine as well. Read through the following [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep) for a basic overview of Object Oriented Design concepts, then consider how re-structuring your application to use classes can help you persist the data.

Hint: [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/ms233843.aspx) will make it much easier to persist & retrieve your classes.

Comment: Thank you Chris:) yeah, just had a similar idea.. but with CSV files:) I do have an abundance of classes. Each one basically having a single task. Reading, storing panel sizes, posts, gates, customer details, one for each product's respective calculations & lookups, and displaying the data. You're absolutely right though.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd answer this if anyone else has a similar problem.

When it comes to saving data, a database is simply the best way to go. When you have multiple users. Writing to text files WILL cause permission problems. The problem I had was not having any columns I could use as foreign keys. This of course is a problem if you want to relate different tables to one customer or order.

The way I solved this issue was to merge each column array to one string

> This code is reads the Double-Swing Gate DatagridView and merges it to a single string... Reading methods are my own. Very simple

```
if (ds_checkBox.Checked)
            {
                int numberOfRows_ds = RowCount_gateDouble();

                ds_Qty = ReadGateDoubleQty(numberOfRows_ds);
                ds_Height = ReadGateDoubleHeight(numberOfRows_ds);
                ds_Width = ReadGateDoubleWidth(numberOfRows_ds);
                ds_total = CalculateTotal_Gates(ds_Qty, numberOfRows_ds);

                string dsgtemp1 = ConvertStringArrayToStringJoin(ds_Qty);
                string dsgtemp2 = ConvertStringArrayToStringJoin(ds_Height);
                string dsgtemp3 = ConvertStringArrayToStringJoin(ds_Width);


                gateDS_data = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}", dsgtemp1, dsgtemp2, dsgtemp3);

                visible_ds = 1;
        }
```

This allows you to store the datagrid into one cell in a dataTable. So for each order, you basically have one dataRow. One row containing the customer's basic details and the order information. Mine is somewhat more complicated now since a customer's order has three stages, quotation -> order -> invoice. BUT, the point is, all the input is in one convenient place.

One can then easily display the order information on each respective datagrid or textbox for what ever reason

```
 ds_checkBox.Checked = true;

                    string theGate_ds = stringArray1[13].ToString();
                    string[] lines_gate_ds = theGate_ds.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    string[] gate_ds_qty = lines_gate_ds[0].Split('.');
                    string[] gate_ds_height = lines_gate_ds[1].Split('.');
                    string[] gate_ds_width = lines_gate_ds[2].Split('.');

                    for (int i = 0; i < gate_ds_qty.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // Create a new row.
                        InputDataSet.Gate_ds_InputRow newOutputRow;

                        newOutputRow = inputDataSet1.Gate_ds_Input.NewGate_ds_InputRow();

                        newOutputRow.gate_ds_qty = string.Format("{0}", gate_ds_qty[i]);
                        newOutputRow.gate_ds_height = string.Format("{0}", gate_ds_height[i]);
                        newOutputRow.gate_ds_width = string.Format("{0}", gate_ds_width[i]);

                        // Add the row to the Region table 
                        this.inputDataSet1.Gate_ds_Input.Rows.Add(newOutputRow);
                        // Save the new row to the database 
                    }
```

I used MySql, Worth learning how to use any sort of database